# project "ctsMgr.exe" raised exception class EDBEngineError with message "unknown database. Alais:.."

Tags: delphi, bde

I was running a Delphi(4) exe . It ran well for few seconds, then raised the error

> project "ctsMgr.exe" raised exception
>   class EDBEngineError with message
>   "unknown  database.
>   Alais:PerDBS". Process stopped. Use Step or
>   Run to continue.

Does the above error imply that Database named "perDBS " is undefined?
Should I "Step" or "run" to  continue?

Regards
-Vas

Answer (score 3):

More likely it means that the alias "PerDBS" exists, but is pointing at a nonexistant DB. Hit run, then fix the alias in BDE Administrator or SQL Explorer, then re-run the application.

If you don't see an alias for PerDBS (in either tool) at all, you'll need to create one.

You don't say which DB the app uses. [This article explains how to set up an alias for dBase.](http://www.jpmartel.com/bu17bde.htm) But the BDE supports many other DB engines. Others are set up similarly, but have different options.

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify that the alias PerDBS exists and point to a valid DB?
Look in the BDE Admin (Control Panel / BDE Administrator) in the Databases tab:
You should see PerDBS under Databases root and you should be able to open it (click the + sign, it turns green and display the info in the Definition tab)